# How can an application know that it is running on Google AppEngine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to find a way to make my Java Appengine application discover whether it is running on the Appengine servers or inside the development environment mini-server. I would like to do this programmatically, not via some property file or other configuration option. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Version 1.3.0](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes) of the SDK added some system properties you can check to get this kind of info:

`com.google.appengine.runtime.{version,environment}`

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice the new runtime properties even though I run 1.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the App Engine the following system variables are set:
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#The_Environment
With `System.getProperty` it should be easy to test if your running in the App Engine.

Comment: It looks like that doc page is a bit out of date as it doesn't include the new google specific properties.